# How to Access dynamically created images with arrow keys

Tags: javascript

I fetched an image series from API URL and I displayed them on screen. but I want to use keyboard arrow keys to navigate(move up, down, left and right) from each image to another image. I know how to use the keycodes. But I do not know how to access these dynamically created images at runtime and control them using the arrow keys. So, I would appreciate if anyone can suggest a solution for this.

Here is my JS code. it fetches and displays the images on the screen correctly

```
   var app = document.getElementById('root');

   var container = document.createElement('div');
   container.setAttribute('class', 'container');
   container.id = 'divid';

    app.appendChild(container);

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', 'https://url of the api', true);
    request.onload = function () {
    var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
        var image;
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        var pic = document.createElement('img');
        pic.src =  data.image;
        container.appendChild(pic);
     }  

  } else {
    var errorMessage = document.createElement('marquee');
    errorMessage.textContent = `Gah, it's not working!`;
    app.appendChild(errorMessage);
  }
}
request.send();
```

My HTML code:

```
<body>

  <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">"></script>
  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
```

part of my CSS code:

```
#root {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
img {
  display: block;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .2s linear;
  margin: 1rem;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do suggest you look for some jcarousel before decide to implement more.

For your particular situation, the workflow might be:

1. Call the api, fetch `data.image` into an array `srcArray`
2. Have an var `currentIndex`. This is the current index of the src of displayed image
3. Have only 1 img div inside container
4. Add [keypress()](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/) handler to change the currentIndex and change the `src` of img div to `srcArray[currentIndex]`

That being said, I think there are many wonderful lib out there for gallery function

Comment: thanks, but i want to move to the next image when i press the arrow key, below or above, left or right of the current image. as the code works for mouse by default can click and movie anywhere on the series of the images given, same is true for the page to move using the four arrow key to move from one corner of the image to  it is neighbor.

Comment: What do you mean by "move to the next image". Does it look somewhat like this https://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/

Comment: not like next and previous but just simply move(pointing to the next) but note that all images are listed in same page.